# iterating through a Django model field produces unwanted format

Tags: django-models, python-3.4

Python3.4 Django1.9 Noob here... :)

I am trying to loop through a Django field but am not getting the desired results, here's the picture:

the models field "info" can hold strings and in some cases python lists. My issue in this case is when it's a list and I  have to iterate through it...

e.g.:

say the "info" field has something like this: ['2016-02-23', '2016-03-01'] and I try to loop through it on the Django1.9 template like this:

```
{% for i in dates %} {{i}}<br /> {% endfor %}
```

I expect to see something like this:

```
2016-02-23
2016-03-01
```

instead I get this:

```
[
'
2
0
1
6
-
0
2
-
2
3
'
,

'
2
0
1
6
-
0
3
-
0
1
'
]
```

which makes me think the mySQL field holding the data is fooling me into thinking this is a python list... my ability to change the format of the database field are limited... any help would be appreciated!

models.py

```
class Events(....
    info = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
dates_list = []
obj_dates = Events.objects.filter(id=id)
for i in obj_dates:
    dates_list.append(i.info)

context = {"dates": dates_list)
```

Django 1.9 template

```
{% for i in dates %} {{i}} {% endfor %}
```

Comment: try: print(dates_list) in views.py just before context = and paste what the result is

Comment: I guess I should've been clear on top... this is what prints ['2016-02-23', '2016-03-01']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just looking at your code

```
obj_dates = Events.objects.filter(id=id)
```

is only going to get you one entry (as you are filtering by id) - you are returning a queryset with only one object.

When you use:

```
for i in obj_dates:
    dates_list.append(i.info)
```

you are appending a string "['2016-02-23', '2016-03-01']"
to dates_list. That is to say that dates_list is just a list containing a single string - it appears to be a list containing a list but it is a list containing a string.

in python strings are iterable, so the template is iterating through one character in the string at a time, thus returning you

```
[
'
2
...
```

**Solutions**

A. The hacky way

```
dates_list.append(list(i.info))
```

that will convert that string "['2016-02-23', '2016-03-01']" into a list

B. a more django-ish approach

Ask yourself can you store dates in a better fashion that as text in a charfield? 
One way to do it is to use a dateField then use m2m so you can store multiple dates.

```
class Events(models.Model)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    dates = models.ManyToManyField(Dates, related_name='events', blank=True)

class Dates(models.Model)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to luke_aus for the help!

I also found something that could work in some cases...
If you see yourself in a situation having to unpack or loop through a Python list stored in a CharField, try this... it worked very well in my case...

**Views.py**

```
import ast

date_list = []
for i in obj: 
    l = {
        'dates': ast.literal_eval(i.info), # i.info is a CharField containing a python list
    }
    dates_list.append(l)
```

**Template**

```
{% for d in dates %}
    {{d}}<br>
{% endfor %}


2016-02-23
2016-03-01
```